# Символ ? в jdbc clob

Tags: oracle, jdbc, clob

Кто может подсказать, как решить проблему с символами `«`, `»`в clob.
После чтения они возвращаются как ??.

```
Connection conn = getConnection();
String str = new String("Bank «MoneyPenny»".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
Clob myClob = conn.createClob();
myClob.setString(1, str);

String res = myClob.getSubString(1, str.length());
System.out.println(res);
```

на выходе -  "Bank ?MoneyPenny?"

Comment: Попробуйте в main оставить только `System.out.println("Bank «MoneyPenny»");`. Что получится?

Comment: Печатает нормально с кавычками.